# How can i route specific traffic through VPN Client

Tags: centos, routing, vpn, openconnect

I have VPN network based CentOS 8 with OpenConnect Package. I need to allow VPN clients to use their local internet for browsing instead of server side. Currently all VPN clients utilising server side internet for browsing.

ip add

```
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:27:d7:19:03:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 200.200.200.3/24 brd 200.200.200.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft 84701sec preferred_lft 84701sec
    inet6 fe80::c53b:410a:9d0f:cc5b/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: vpns0: <POINTOPOINT,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1434 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 10.10.10.1 peer 10.10.10.76/32 scope global vpns0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8da5:409d:a886:5bfb/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip route

```
default via 200.200.200.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.10.10.76 dev vpns0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.10.1 
200.200.200.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 200.200.200.3 metric 100
```

firewall-cmd --list-all

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eno1
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client http https ipsec ssh
  ports: 500/udp 4500/udp 443/tcp 443/udp 80/tcp
  protocols: 
  forward: no
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 
    rule protocol value="ah" accept
    rule protocol value="esp" accept
    rule family="ipv4" source address="10.10.10.0/24” masquerade
```

netstat -rn

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         200.200.200.1   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eno1
10.10.10.76     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 vpns0
200.200.200.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eno1
```

Comment: Remove the option to route everything across the VPN and define routes for just the networks that should use it

Comment: Can you please explain bit more detailed it will save my time to understand . I’v been trying to solve this since 1 last week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was solved by disabling default route and ad local route in ocserv.conf file

```
 route = xx.xx.xx.0/xx
 route = 10.10.10.0/255.255.255.0
 route = 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0
 route = fef4:db8:1000:1001::/64
#route = default
```